# Upload file to S3 with PUT and form-data

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js

I am trying to upload an image file (jpeg) to AWS S3 via the PUT interface, and I am getting the error SignatureDoesNotMatch.

On my server, I have an Express node.js app with an endpoint to create a signed url.

```js
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const config = require('./config');

// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: config.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, 
    secretAccessKey: config.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    region: 'us-east-1'
});
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

const app = express();
const awsS3Router = express.Router();

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// AWS S3 REST endpoints
awsS3Router.get('/getImageDrop', function(req, res) {
    if(!req.query.filename) {
        res.status(400).send('Request query is empty!');
    }
    const s3Params = {
        Bucket: config.S3_BUCKET,
        ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
        ACL: 'public-read',
        Key: req.query.filename,
        Expires: 6000
    };
    s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', s3Params, function(err, data) {
        if(err){
            console.error('ERROR: ' + err);
            return res.end();
        }
        const returnData = {
            signedRequest: data,
            url: 'https://' + config.S3_BUCKET + '.s3.amazonaws.com/' + req.query.filename
        };
        app.locals.s3SignedUrl = returnData.signedRequest;
        res.write(JSON.stringify(returnData));
        res.end();
    });
});
app.use('/aws/s3', awsS3Router);

module.exports = app;
```

On the client side, I can call this endpoint and get a signed S3 url back. The response url format is:
https://[bucket name].s3.amazonaws.com/878CF5A4-D013-435F-BF7D-F45AB69E580F.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=[AWS access key]&Content-Type=image%2Fjpeg&Expires=1521244920&Signature=[Signature]&x-amz-acl=public-read

The client code has a function to upload the file to the signed S3 url.

```js
async uploadImageToS3BucketAsync(imageFileUri, fileSize, signedUrl) {
        const fileName = PathParse(imageFileUri).base;
        let form = new FormData();
        form.append('files[0]', {
            'uri': imageFileUri,
            'name': fileName,
            'type': 'image/jpeg'
        });
        //form.append('photo', imageFileUri);
        console.info('INFO: PUT ' + signedUrl.signedRequest + ': Request: ' + JSON.stringify(form));
     return fetch((signedUrl.signedRequest), {
      method: 'PUT',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg', 'Content-Length': fileSize },
            body: form
     })
         .then(function(res) {
                if (res.ok) {
                    console.info('INFO: PUT ' + JSON.stringify(signedUrl) + ': Response: ' + JSON.stringify(res));
                    return res.json();
                } else {
                    console.error('Failed to upload image to S3 bucket!');
                    console.error('ERROR: ' + JSON.stringify(res));
                    alert('Failed to upload image to S3 bucket!!');
                }
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                console.error('ERROR: Request failed', err);
            });
    }
```

Unfortunately, the upload fails systematically with a 403 error:

```html
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
```

I am guessing I am missing something in the request headers of the PUT call, but I am not sure what it is. Has anyone found a solution for this in node.js?

Comment: You don't use `PUT` with a form structure.  `PUT` expects the raw binary body.

Comment: Thank you, so I decided to go with a POST to upload the file through form-data. I used s3.createPresignedPost() to generate a pre-signed url I can use in a POST call with form-data. I am now getting a new error: <Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Invalid according to Policy: Policy Condition failed: [\"eq\", \"$Content-Type\", \"image/jpeg\"]</Message></Error>. If someone has pointers on how to resolve the above error. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: The error indicates that your policy requires the form to contain a field named `Content-Type` with value `image/jpeg` but that the field is missing or does not have that value.

Comment: I believe I am passing the Content-Type in the createPresignedPost correctly. Or should it go elsewhere?

const s3Params = {
        ...
        Conditions: [
            ...
            {'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'}
        ]
    };
    s3.createPresignedPost(s3Params, function(err, data) { ... });

Comment: This is what sets the *constraint*.  You also need the wire equivalent of `<input type="hidden"  name="Content-Type" value="image/jpeg" />` in the actual `POST`.

Comment: This is what I have in my form, and I am passing the Content-Type there too:
let form = new FormData();
form.append('acl', 'public-read');
for (const field in signedUrl.fields) {
   form.append(field, signedUrl.fields[field]);
}
form.append('Content-Type': 'image/jpeg');
form.append('file', imageFileUri);

Comment: The createPresignedPost() is run from an AWS lambda function. Could this be the issue? The form-data is run within a React Native app.

Comment: In the request of the POST, I can see Content-Type being set to null... I am not sure why that is since I'm setting it to image/jpeg in my code.

Comment: If I change the form-data to use a JSON for the file input, I am now getting a different error:
form.append('files[0]', { 'uri': imageFileUri, 'filename': fileName, 'type': 'image/jpeg' });
The new error is Your POST request fields preceeding the upload file was too large.

Comment: Explanation: [*"The form data and boundaries (excluding the contents of the file) cannot exceed 20K."*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTForms.html) It's not clear why you might be overrunning that limit.  If you are sure that your form is smaller, this suggests that S3 is not correctly finding the start of your actual file.  Try uploading a very very small file and see what error you encounter.

Comment: I solved my upload image file issue by reverting my code to use a PUT pre-signed s3 url and uploading through XmlHttpRequest.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to retrieve the file from the FormData instance after appending it.

```js
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('File', selectedFile);
fetch(
    presignedPutUrl,
    {
        method: 'PUT',
        body: formData.get("File"),
    }
)
```

Thanks @[Michael - sqlbot] for the comment that got me here.

> You don't use PUT with a form structure. PUT expects the raw binary body.